# Parsing JSON Swift 4

Tags: arrays, json, swift, swift4

Here is the JSON I am trying to parse from the Strava API:

```
{
"firstname": "Evan",
"lastname": "Arthur",
"city": "",
"state": "",
"country": "",
"sex": "M",
"measurement_preference": "feet",
"ftp": 285,
"bikes": [
    {
        "id": "b4770368",
        "primary": true,
        "name": "Felt Disc",
        "resource_state": 2,
        "distance": 2528687
    }
]
}
```

I am trying to access some of the entries and create an object from them. Here is my Athlete class:

```
import Foundation

struct athlete: Codable{
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let sex: String
    let measurement: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
         case firstName = "firstname"
         case lastName = "lastname"
         case sex = "sex"
         case measurement = "measurement_preference"
         case bikes = "bikes"
    }

    struct Bike: Codable {
         let name: String
         let distance: String
     //  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey{
     //     case name = "name"
     //     case distance = "distance"
     //  }
    }

    let bikes: [Bike]

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.firstName = try container.decode(String.self, forKey:      .firstName)
        self.lastName = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .lastName)
        self.sex = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .sex)
        self.measurement = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .measurement)
        self.bikes = try container.decode([Bike].self, forKey: .bikes)
   } 
}
```

I try to parse it with this code:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let definition = try? decoder.decode(athlete.self, from: jsonData)
```

I know I am retrieving the api correctly and I can access parse all the fields before "bikes," but I cannot access bikes. With this code, the decoder.decode() fails. How do I properly access the array and decode it?

Comment: Why did you add your own `init` method? You aren't doing anything special. Try removing your custom `init` and it will likely work. If not, post the error in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is all just fine, except for one thing. In your declaration of Bike, change

```
let distance: String
```

to

```
let distance: Int
```

---

Okay, now that I've said that, I'm going to take you to task. Your last line is:

```
let definition = try? decoder.decode(athlete.self, from: jsonData)
```

That is very foolish. This method returns an error telling you exactly what the problem is, and you are throwing that error away! Either change `try?` to `try!` to force a crash that will log the error in the console, or change it to `try` and wrap the whole thing in a `try/catch` blog and log it yourself:

```
do {
    let definition = try decoder.decode(athlete.self, from: jsonData)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

That is how I knew what mistake you were making. Not because I'm smart. Not because I have sharp eyes. Neither is true! It was because I logged the error, instead of throwing it away as you did. If you had done that, you wouldn't have needed to ask this question in the first place.

Comment: Also, rmaddy is right to this extent: your code will work just as well if you omit the `init(from:)` implementation, as it does nothing of any interest. The autosynthesized implementation is fine here.